# What is そういうの referring to?

Tags: meaning

In the below, what is そういうの referring to? Should what she says be understood as something like:
みさき先輩のこととなると目ざとい, or is it referring to something else?

> 「どこかケガでもされたんじゃ！」
>
> 「……いや、そういうんじゃなくてね」
>
> 「うそ！　みさき先輩のことですからわかります！　わたし**そういうの**目ざといんですから！」

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> わたしそういうの目ざといんですから！
>
> I am quick to notice things like this / this kind of things!

Here she's probably saying she is good at noticing someone being a little out of shape. そういうの is "someone's physical condition being bad" here. そういうん in the previous sentence also refers to the same thing.

This そういうの is not みさき先輩のこと because みさき先輩のこと is already generic enough.